# Problem installing a program

Tags: software-installation

A program I need to use wont install.  It comes as a .deb file but when I try to install it says "wrong architecture i386".  How can I get it to work.  This is with ubuntu 11.10 (dual core version).

I did get the program to run on a version of 10.10 (single core) running on virtual box.

Comment: What is your architecture? ( 'uname -m' )

Comment: if you post in your question what this .deb file is and where you have downloaded it, we'll be able to advise you better.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are trying to install a 32 bit program on a 64 bit ubuntu. You need to find 64 bit version of your program or try to use 32 bit version of ubuntu.

Comment: With multiarch, you can (although a 64-bit version of the app is still probably preferable)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64-bit architecture, you can still install and run 32-bit programs if your processor supports it (which it probably does). To do so, run `sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i yourpackage.deb`.

Comment: There's no question of processor support. Also, with multiarch, you mustn't `--force-architecture`